# How to pass app = express() into another module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working on a basic Node app, I have app.js which requires most of my dependencies, then I have another module which just require `http` and `url`.

However in this other module I need to pass my express app into it, because I'd rather not have to set var app = express() again inside the sub module.

How would you pass app into my get_twitter.js?

Main app.js

```
var express     = require('express');
var app         = express();
var hello       = require('./custom_hello');
var gettwitter  = require('./get_twitter');

hello();

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.gettwitter();

app.listen(9000);
console.log('listening on 9000...');
```

get_twitter module:

```
/* =========================================
GET TWITTER Node module
========================================= */

var http = require('http');
var url  = require('url');

app.get('/tweets/:username', function(req, response) {

    var username = req.params.username;

    options = {
        protocol: "http:",
        host: "api.twitter.com",
        pathname: "/1/statuses/user_timeline.json",
        query: { screen_name: username, count: 10 }
    }

    var twitterUrl = url.format(options);
    request(twitterUrl).pipe(response);

});
```

Currently if I run this as is, `app` will of course throw the **ReferenceError: app is not defined error**.

Comment: `var gettwitter  = require('./get_twitter')(app);`?

Comment: I tried that too, but still get `ReferenceError: app is not defined` in my get_twitter.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap your module in a function and export it. Then you can pass your app into the function to use in the module.

```
//get_twitter.js

function Get_Twitter(app){

    var http = require('http');
    var url  = require('url');

    app.get('/tweets/:username', function(req, response) {

        var username = req.params.username;

        options = {
            protocol: "http:",
            host: "api.twitter.com",
            pathname: "/1/statuses/user_timeline.json",
            query: { screen_name: username, count: 10 }
        }

        var twitterUrl = url.format(options);
        request(twitterUrl).pipe(response);

    });

}

exports = Get_Twitter;
```

Then in your main app, invoke it

```
var Get_Twitter = require("get_twitter")(app);
```

Comment: If I use `var Get_Twitter = require("./get_twitter")(app);` I get object is not a function. I remove that `(app)` and then I get the same error on `Get_Twitter(app);` in app.js

Comment: remove `app.gettwitter();` from your main app

Comment: I also I have get_twitter.js in the root and not in the node_modules folder so had to put back `./`